# How do I make an anonymous method run in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, expression

I'm trying to build a generic method that EF4.1 to look in both the Database and the Local memory for a particular row in a table that matches a particular criteria.

So far, this is what I have this.

This is the caller.

```
dbEntities.MyTables.LocalAndDb(delegate(MyTable s)
                { return s.Description.Contains("test"); });
```

This is LocalAndDb

```
public static object LocalAndDb<T>(this DbSet<T> myTable, Func<T, bool> function) where T : class
{   
    // look in local 
    var item = myTable.Local.Where(o => function((T)o)).FirstOrDefault()
    // if not exist, look in the database
    if (item == null)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = (u) => function(u);
        item = myTable.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return item;
}
```

The problem is with this line.

```
    item = myTable.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
```

When it calls the database, it throws this error.

"The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

I imagine it's because I'm passing in an anonymous method and it doesn't know how to turn this into SQL. I thought converting it to an Expression object would do the trick but it's still not working for me.

What do I need to do to make a anonymous method become something that LINQ can turn into SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this work, you need to pass the lambda expression to `LocalAndDb` as an expression tree (so that LINQ to Entities can analyze the code and translate it to SQL):

```
public static object LocalAndDb<T>(this DbSet<T> myTable, 
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr) where T : class {
    // ...
    if (item == null) {
        item = myTable.Where(expr).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return item;
}
```

Then, of course, the problem is that you cannot execute the expression tree when checking the in-memory data. One way to solve this is to use the `Compile` method of `Expression<T>`, but that will be a bit inefficient (depending on your scenario).

Another option is to just pass the condition as both function and expression tree:

```
public static object LocalAndDb<T>(this DbSet<T> myTable, 
    Func<T, boo> function, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr) where T : class {
    var item = myTable.Local.Where(o => function((T)o)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (item == null) {
        item = myTable.Where(expr).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return item;
}

table.LocalAndDb(t => t.Foo > 10, t => t.Foo > 10);
```

This is a bit ugly, but it doesn't require inefficient compilation at runtime. If you want a slightly more sophisticated solution, then you can define your own type to keep pre-compiled functions:

```
class Precompiled<T1, T2> {
  public Precompiled(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> expr) {
    this.Expression = expr;
    this.Function = expr.Compile();
  }
  public Expression<Func<T1,T2>> Expression { get; private set; }
  public Func<T1,T2> Function { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Compile worked! Thanks thanks thanks! I'm a complete newbie when it comes to EF. But I will now do some research on the performance aspects. It seems from what you're saying that when you "compile" the expression, whether it's in the method, or in the signature or in the Precompiled constructor, this affects performance?

Comment: @stickman - The idea in of the `Precompiled` class is that you could easily construct it just once (to call `Compile` once) and then use the result repreatedly in multiple calls to `LocalAndDb`, so that the expression isn't recompiled during every call.